# What is the json format to send to server(JIRA Service Desk)?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I have created a form in mobile app, Now I want to users, if they submit the form, It will generate as a Ticket in JIRA.

Now problem is that, I am unable to get json format, that I need to post to my JIRA Dashboard.

My base URL - https://MyCompany.atlassian.net/projects/ST/queues/custom/1

I am refering this URL for integration-

https://confluence.atlassian.com/servicedeskcloud

Comment: Take a look on jira rest api reference documentation: https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.12.0/?_ga=2.217235414.1593394338.1538913782-180945325.1499538424
jira service desk rest api ref: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-servicedesk/REST/3.15.0/?_ga=2.55163883.1593394338.1538913782-180945325.1499538424

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be looking at the JIRA REST API documentation found here: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/

Specifically:  https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/#api-api-2-issue-post